# how i can give more resources to a db instance in aurora aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I use aurora database engine and my instances are a db.t3.small, i have an api that consume calls to database and when I have a number of users consuming requests of my database, they dont have the enough mem to response so i have two instances:
one writer: where i can call and put information
and the other one is reader: I'm not sure what it works for.

i want to resolve this problem with a policy rule where i make extra replica when the cpu is above 40% of cpu but this is not a soluction i think so.

Comment: Does auto scaling not work for you? As this is precisely the type of scenario it should be able to handle.

Comment: Yep, this is a standard use-case for autoscaling. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Integrating.AutoScaling.html) for a brief walkthrough.

Comment: "i want to resolve this problem with a policy rule where i make extra replica when the cpu is above 40% of cpu" You just described AWS Aurora autoscaling

Answer (score 1):

A better way to resolve this issue if you are using Aurora is to simply use Aurora Serverless, this will scale the compute and disk space automatically, and then save you cost when it is not being used.

Comment: and if i use Provisioned data base , can i scale the resource? or can it be scaled in another way?